# Different number of samples for different parts of a render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, noise-reduction

Is there any way to use different number of samples in different parts of the scene? I'd like to have higher number of samples only where the glass material is but lower on the rest because I dont need that much to get rid of the noise:

[image]

Comment: Render the elements as different images and composite later

Comment: That wouldnt make the image loose information from indirect light reflected by the rest of the objects in the scene?

Comment: Hmmm... This is a really good image, but cagaton is right, you may just have to render the 2 different images and composite layer. And with the bounced light from the other objects, you can play around with the Bounce settings in the Render tab, you may be able to find some good info there.

Comment: ok, thx a lot for your answers, i will try the separate layers rendering and will read some info about "faking" the rest of the objects information :)

Comment: @cegaton Might this be a good candidate for Branched Path Tracing? Upping glossy/transmission samples? ... I'm trying to learn about this area myself...